# How to compute robust normalized relative variance of a small set of numbers

Tags: variance, standard-deviation, descriptive-statistics

I am looking for a way to calculate a statistic that represents the normalized robust relative variance or spread of any relatively small set of numbers. Concretely, I would like to compute a statistic that is closer to ~0 when low spread, and >>0 when there is high spread, regardless of the sample size and magnitude of the sample. Assume numbers might come from a non-normal distribution.

My end goal is to have a function that would take any set of numbers of any size and magnitude and compute the robustly normalized relative spread in a way that I could apply a cutoff parameter and return True/False when such threshold is bypassed.

For example, imagine this array of numbers:

```
2.1 2.4 2.6 2.5 2.3 2.1 2.4 2.5 8.5 8.9
```

Having a cutoff value of 0.5, I should expect the function to tell me that there is not much spread on that set, as the statistic would be close to 0 and thus ~0 < 0.5.

However, if having this set instead

```
1.1 2.3 3.1 4.5 5.1 6.5 7.1 8.1 9.4 10.2
```

The relative variance should be higher, e.g. closer or greater than 1, and hence the function would return True given ~1 > 0.5.

I tried several methods, such as `std(x)/mean(x)` or `std(x)/median(x)`, but I am not sure whether those are the best choices for my problem.

Comment: This is a Holy Grail problem without more detail. Non-normal doesn't tie anything down but rather widens the problem! Your question equivocates between wanting a measure of spread (in the simplest case a measure with the same units and dimensions as the data) and wanting one of relative spread (free of units and dimensions); The ratio SD / mean has a name  _coefficient of variation_ and cautionary literature here on CV to the effect that it works well if and only if all values are positive and it makes sense to take logarithms. The ratio IQR / median works best in the same circumstances.

Comment: I would start in the first instance with interquartile range (IQR) or more generally differences of the form $(1 - p)$ quantile $- p$ quantile, e.g. $95$% point $- 5$% point.

Comment: In my scenario, there would be only positive values (use case is prices) and taking logarithms would make sense. Would then iqr/median or sd/mean be among the best and most robust methods to consider? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: The SD of logarithms is essentially equivalent to the coefficient of variation. If there are rogue prices you might want IQR of logarithms. (As a simple example, I sometimes see sky-high rogue prices on Amazon for a used book.  A benign explanation is that the seller does not have a copy to sell but doesn't want to delete the entry because one might become available at any time. Another explanation is that they are fishing for idiots or the enormously rich who really would pay anything. Either way such a price should usually be ignored.)

Comment: Ideally my function would employ two sub-functions: one trying to find the outliers of the set by using the modified z-scores (idea gathered from Iglewicz and Hoaglin (1993)); and the other one trying to compute the robust coefficient of variation. The flow would be: if there are no outliers detected, that means that either there aren't any, of there is too much variance in the set that outliers cannot be defined within.

Comment: You're widening the question and I see why but won't willingly get sucked into that beyond a few remarks. I am sceptical of all attempts at universal rules for outliers. David Hoaglin I count as a personal friend and I think he would want to emphasise the limited context of that paper. Seems to me that taking logarithms of prices will get you most of the way there. Otherwise put. decision rules to choose decision rules are hard to find and your own goals perhaps will and should drive what you do.

Comment: Beautifully put. I will take your remarks and considerations. Thanks for the advice, Nick!